# how to use my_alloc for _all_ new calls in C++?

Tags: c++, memory-management, constructor, new-operator

Imagine I'm in C-land, and I have

```
 void* my_alloc(size_t size);
 void* my_free(void*);
```

then I can go through my code and replace all calls to malloc/free with my_alloc/my_free.

How, I know that *given* a class Foo, I can do placement new; I can also overload the new operator. However, is there a way to do this for *all* my C++ classes? (i.e. I want to use my own allocator for new and new[]; but I don't want to run through and hack every class I have defined.)

Thanks!

Comment: C++ allows you to provide your own implementations of global new and delete.

Comment: `my_free` shouldn't return `void*`. Just saying.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In global scope,

```
 void* operator new(size_t s) { return my_alloc(s); }
 void operator delete(void* p) { my_free(p); }
 void* operator new[](size_t s) { return my_alloc(s); }
 void operator delete[](void* p) { my_free(p); }
```

Comment: actually, there are 12 functions to replace: new/delete, new/delete nothrow, placement new/delete - and each with an array version. See here: http://www.gamedev.net/community/forums/viewreply.asp?ID=2471345

Comment: @Tobias Good point about the nothrow versions, but the placement operators don't need replacing

Comment: Note: this approach will only replace new/delete *in your own code*.

new/delete calls in statically-linked dependencies will not be modified.

Comment: @James: May I ask why? I think I read that you must not forget placement new in case someone uses it.

Comment: @Tobias: You *cannot* replace placement-new. Think about what the function does and you'll understand why. (Hint: Nothing!)

Answer (score 2):

Define custom global new and delete operator functions :

```
void* operator new(size_t size) 
{
    //do something
    return malloc(size);
}

void operator delete(void *p) 
{
    //do something     
     free(p); 
}
```

**Placement new** can be used when you want to create object from the pre-allocated buffer.

Frequent use of new and delete will cause memory fregmentation and it costs to memory access and allocation.So the whole idea of placement new is to create memory pool at the program start and destroy it at program end and all request for memory just returns free memory location from the pool.

Comment: This is a replacement of the new operator, not 'placement new': http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/dtors.html#faq-11.10

Comment: I know that both are different.
Ok i have removed the confusion and removed "Thus" word.

Answer (score 0):

Here is something I found. that may help.

```
template<typename T>
T* my_alloc(size_t size)
{
    return new T[size];
}

template<typename T>
void my_free(T* ptr)
{
    delete[] ptr;
}
```

And here is the example used:

```
int main(void)
{
    char* pChar = my_alloc<char>(10);
    my_free(pChar);
}
```

Alternative Example:

```
void* my_alloc (size_t size)
{
   return ::operator new(size);
}

void my_free (void* ptr)
{
   ::operator delete(ptr);
}
```

All this code should be tested.